# Will using a static method affect performance when running the same method in parallel?

Tags: java, static

I have a util class, with a private constructor, and all methods being static. The reason being, none of the methods share any objects as the class doesn't store any state. However I'm wondering if these static methods, if invoked in parallel, would cause any requests to block? Does the fact that static variables being stored in shared memory locations affect this?
Any help in understanding the underlying execution mechanism would be much appreciated.

Below is the class I'm talking about.

```
public final class PersonUtil {
    private static IPerson person;

    private PersonUtil() {
    }

    public static PersonOutput generatePerson(final PersonInput personInput) {
        if (isParamProvided()) {
            person = new MyPerson();
        } else {
            person = new LegacyPerson();
        }
        return person.create(personInput);
    }

    public static void assignState(final String guid) {
      //call AssignState API for given guid
    }

    public static String getGuidForId(final String id) {
        //call GetGuid API for the given ID
    }

    public static String getPersonNameByGuid(final String guid) {
        // call DescribePerson API
    }
}
```

Comment: Do these methods *modify* static variables? How do you ensure thread safety?

Comment: I updated the question with my class, they're all unrelated methods and they don't modify any static variables. They all do their own API calls with the given input params

Comment: If the static methods call something that can block, such as printing to `System.out` or uses any other shared resource protected by some synchronization mechanism, then it can itself block.

Comment: In your example, it will depend on how exactly these requests to these APIs are implemented - do they use a shared socket of some kind? How is session handling implemented? etc. But basically, being `static`  changes nothing in that regard, the same considerations would also apply to instance methods.

Comment: The example as given really shouldn't be static at all, or at least there should not be a static field `person`.

Comment: Do you really think, it’s helpful to post code like `public static void methodName(final String guid) {
      //call MethodName API for given guid
    }`? Are we supposed to reason about the thread safety of a comment or about code you didn’t include in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may have a concurrency problem here when you call `generatePerson`, because this method is impacting the static field `person`.

Imagine that you have two threads:

- One calls `generatePerson` with an argument that causes `person = new MyPerson()`
- Another calls `generatePerson` with an argument that causes `person = new LegacyPerson()`

If both threads are concurrent, then it can happen that:

1. The first thread sets `person = new MyPerson()`
2. The second thread right after sets `person = new LegacyPerson()`
3. The first thread calls `create()` on a `person` which is `LegacyPerson` (because thread 2 sets it as such on the previous statement), but it should have called it on an instance of `MyPerson` instead

To avoid this, you should declare `person` as `volatile` (that will ensure that all threads see the same thing when it's time to read the variable) and then you should declare your `generatePerson` as synchronized, so that only one thread at a time can access it:

```
private static volatile IPerson person;

public static synchronized PersonOutput generatePerson(final PersonInput personInput) {
    if (isParamProvided()) {
        person = new MyPerson();
    } else {
        person = new LegacyPerson();
    }
    return person.create(personInput);
}
```

A better solution though would be possible if `MyPerson` and `LegacyPerson` don't hold any state. If that was the case, then you could declare two instances as `final`:

```
private static final IPerson myPerson = new MyPerson();
private static final IPerson legacyPerson = new LegacyPerson();
```

And so you change the `createPerson` method to do this:

```
public static PersonOutput createPerson(final PersonInput personInput) {
    if (isParamProvided()) {
        return myPerson.create(personInput);
    } else {
        return legacyPerson.create(personInput);
    }
}
```

Like that, you never write the static fields concurrently and so your static method becomes agnostic from concurrency issues.

Note: I'm providing the example on `createPerson` because it's the only method for which you're showing your code. You should apply the same logic on all the API endpoints, without seeing the code we can't know whether there are other concurrency issues or not.

Suggestion: avoid concurrency when you can. It's always a source of flaky issues and should be used only when it's strictly necessary. In the second example that I provided you're avoiding it, try to do the same in the other endpoints.

Comment: In the question’s code, `person` is never read, except within the method that just has written to it. So the better option would be to make `person` a local variable within the method itself. Unless there are other accesses to `person` not shown in the question, of course. In that case, the code would still be broken, as declaring the variable `volatile` is not enough to prevent race conditions.

Comment: @Holger person is used to create an output from an input. The instance of person can be one or the other. So yes, it is read, even if not explicitly like with a getter. And yes the volatile is probably not the best solution here, I've proposed another one right after.

Comment: I already said, it is “never read, *except within the method that just has written to it*”. The simplest fix is to turn `person` into a local variable, that will work, regardless of whether `MyPerson` or `LegacyPerson` hold state, are mutable, or thread safe. Actually, you don’t even need a variable at all: `return (isParamProvided()? new MyPerson(): new LegacyPerson()) .create(personInput);`

Comment: @Holger sure, that's another option. But you would be creating a new instance each time you're called. With the solution I proposed above, you only create it statically once and reuse it everytime. That of course, under the assumption that the classes have no state.

Comment: Creating a new instance each time the method is called, is exactly what the original code does, it just unnecessarily inserts a race condition through a shared variable. By using a local variable, the race condition is eliminated without changing the original program logic and without needing assumptions about the other classes. We don’t know whether caching the objects would work (i.e. whether they’re thread safe) nor whether it is actually necessary (i.e. whether their construction is expensive).

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a performance problem. If you don't have `synchronized` blocks or `synchronized` methods, you won't have any performance problem.

Most probably you will get **concurrency problems**. If multiple persons are generated concurrently by different threads, only a single person will be assigned to the field and you won't be able to predict witch one.

Even worse, the assigned person will be possibly replaced over the time without any explicit assignments (see the next paragraph).

You will definitely get **visibility problems**. If one thread assigns the static field `person`, it won't be visible for another thread for sometime (it could be microseconds or minutes). Define person as `volatile` to avoid it.

```
private static volatile IPerson person;
```

And of course you must ensure, that classes `MyPerson` and `LegacyPerson` are thread-safe. All the fields of these two classes must be `final` or `volatile`. If it cannot be reached, you will need `synchronized` blocks including related performance drawbacks.

Comment: It's true, but in this example the problem is not only about reading the value of person but rather about using it. If one thread sets person to some value and then another thread uses it without having set itself, it may be using the wrong instance of person so the fact of person being volatile doesn't really avoid the concurrency issue.

Comment: I would suggest the initialization on the person happens only once. Otherwise the whole code has no sense...

Comment: I agree with you, proposed that in my answer.

Comment: When you assume that the initialization of `person` is supposed to happen only once, you’d need a mechanism to ensure that property. Declaring the variable `volatile` does not. On the other hand, if you have a mechanism that can guaranty that `person` is initialized exactly once, that mechanism may make `volatile` unnecessary.

Comment: DEFINITELY NOT. Even if you initialize a field only once, you still need "volatile" in case of usage in the mutli-thread context. Alternatively you can use "final", but it won't work in case of static field.

Comment: If a field is final it means it's immutable. Hence you can safely use it in a multi-threading context because its value simply never changes.

Comment: Whether you need `volatile`, depends on the mechanism you used to ensure that the variables are initialized only once. You didn’t name one, so you can not make any assumption. But, as you said, `final` would be one alternative. The other would be any external synchronization mechanism. An `AtomicBoolean` holding the initialization state or a `Semaphore`, for example. Or just making the `generatePerson` method `synchronized`. Neither of these options requires `person` to be `volatile`.

Comment: 2Holger It is very simple and doesn't require assumptions. There is only one documented case in Java, where you can omit volatile/final. It is if all the multi-threaded access (reading and writing) to the field is synchronized using "synchronized" keyword. All other cases including AtomicBoolean, Semaphore or whatever else require volatile/final on all the involved fields.

Comment: It’s definitely not simple. There’s a reason, the language specification has a [long chapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html) about the topic. Half truths and made-up rules do not help here. I don’t care if you don’t know when you can omit the `volatile` modifier, sprinkle it over all your code if you like. But at least you have to understand, when `volatile` does not help.